# Modify PHP file Using jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to add a value from a selected  in my html into a PHP file  using jQuery. I have 2 php file, chainmenu.php and function.php. function.php contain 2 functions to get some data from my database. chainmenu.php is used to show the result of a function from function.php. It requires a variable, that is a value from selected option in my html. I was able to retrieve the value, but my problem is that my $.post function doesn't work. I dont know where is the error, is it in my chainmenu.php or in my function.php.

This is my code

jQuery CODE

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#trafo").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#gi").change(function(){
                $("select#trafo").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#trafo").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#gi option:selected").attr('value');
                $("select#trafo").html("<Option>"+id+"</Option>");
                $.post("chainmenu.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#trafo").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#trafo").html(data);
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Function.php

```
 <?php class SelectList
    {

//$this->conn is working fine here

    public function ShowGI()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM gi";
                $res = mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql);  
                if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>=1){
                    $category = '<option value="0">Pilih GI</option>';
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                    {
                        $category .= '<option value="' . $row['idgi'] . '">' . $row['namegi'] . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                return $category;
            }

            public function ShowIt()
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM It WHERE idgi=$_POST[id]";
                $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                $type = '<option value="0">Choose/option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    $type .= '<option value="' . $row['idIt'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
                return $type;
            }
               }

    $opt = new SelectList();
    ?>
```

chainmenu.php

```
<?php include "/opsi.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowIt(); ?>
```

HTML Code

```
<head>
<!-- the script here -->
</head>
<body>
<select id=gi>
<option value="0"> Select </option>
</select>
<select id=It>
<!-- chainmenu.php result should be here -->
</select>

</body>
```

This explanation a little bit messy, but i hope anyone could help me and give me some good advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using Chrome and use the dev tools to inspect what's going on. Open the dev window and then click on the network tab, clear everything out and then hit your submit. Go back to your dev tab and look at the response. Also look on the console tab. This should give you some sort of hint.

Comment: in post you are passing chainmenu.php but using $_POST['id'] in function.php!!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this in chainmenu.php

```
<?php include "/opsi.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowIt($_POST['id']); ?>
```

in function.php replace ShowIt() method like below,

```
public function ShowIt($id)
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM It WHERE idgi=$id";
                $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
                $type = '<option value="0">Choose/option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                {
                    $type .= '<option value="' . $row['idIt'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
                return $type;
            }
```

Comment: alert(id) in jquery what comes?

Comment: echo var_dump($_POST) in chainmenu.php gives what?

Comment: alert(id) gives me the exact value of the selected option value. It seems the problem is after this code :
var id = $("select#gi option:selected").attr('value');

echo var_dump(S_POST) didnt give anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos in ShowIt() function for e.g `$type = '<option value="0">Choose/option>';` the tag isn't closed properly.
In the jquery code you are retrieving the value and adding the html to select tag having id trafo. whereas in html code the id of the select is It.

```
<select id=It>
 <!-- chainmenu.php result should be here -->
</select>
```

Comment: yeah, i admit it. I'll edit it. 
after i fix those syntax error, i found out that the main problem is in $.post order. my chainmenu.php cannot fetch "id" variable from script..